# Sincronizar archivos con google drive

Tags: xamarin.forms

Buenas alguien me podría guiar para poder sincronizar una parte del desarrollo que estoy haciendo.
Voy a desarrollar en local con una persistencia Sqlite, bien llegados a esto quiero que esta db se sincronice con google drive.
Saben de algún nuget o plugin para poder hacer esta acción, la idea es máximo mover entre 20-30 Mb

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones lo que generaría su cierre.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir @Bicho, me puedes explicar qué me diices con 'basada en opiniones' ??

Comment: El sitio te ayuda con problemas que puedas tener con el código, al decir **"me podría guiar"**, se pueden generar diferentes opiniones de cómo se podría resolver un problema.

Comment: Ok, comprendo, lo que pasa que no se como guiar en el desarrollo, si en la finalidad. Paso a detallar, mi idea es subir un archivo a google drive desde xamarin (c#) existe algun paquete nuget que hayáis utilizado.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

tal vez esto te sirva

```
public static async Task ComparteAsync(string ArchivoTxt, string titulo)
        {

            bPath =  ArchivoTxt;


            await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
            {

                
                Title = titulo,
                File = new ShareFile(bPath)
                


            });
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y lee [answer]; no es bien recibido responder a preguntas de baja calidad, tampoco las respuestas que solamente exponen código